# Multiplication of a stream in Petite scheme

Tags: scheme

I got some homework that i'm a bit lost about. Given a stream of natural numbers, I should be able to produce a new stream (twice-the-stream) where all the elements are multiplied by two.

```
(define stream-of-natural-numbers
    (letrec ([produce (lambda (current-natural-number)
                  (cons current-natural-number
                        (lambda ()
                          (produce (1+ current-natural-number)))))])
(produce 0)))
```

I came up with the following code, but nothing seems to work and I'm lost now.

```
(define twice-the-stream
    (lambda (n)
        (letrec ([produce (lambda (current next)
                              (cons (* 2 current)
                                    (lambda ()
                                       (produce (current next) (force (next))))))])
  (produce (car n) (force (cdr n))))))
```

> (twice-the-stream stream-of-natural-numbers)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
(define twice-the-stream
    (lambda (n)
        (letrec ([produce (lambda (current next)
                              (cons (* 2 current)
                                    (lambda ()
                                       (produce (current next) (force (next))))))])
                              ;; this is wrong: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  (produce (car n) (force (cdr n))))))
```

You've already forced the `(cdr n)` at that point; now `next` is not a function, it's a stream -- a cons pair of *its* current number and *its* stream-tail.

`current` is not a function either. It's a number, already used in producing the doubled number above that call.

To lessen the cognitive load, rename your variables to remind you what they are,

```
(define twice-the-stream
    (lambda (numbers-stream)
        (letrec ([produce (lambda (current-num next-str)
                              (cons (* 2 current-num)
                                    (lambda ()
                                       (produce (current-element next-str)
                                                (force (next-elements next-str))))))])
  (produce (car numbers-stream) (force (cdr numbers-stream))))))
```

and now you can see that you got confused by *overly-suggestive* (and under-specialized) *naming*, conflating in your mind "current" number with "current number" function, and "next" stream with "next stream" function. By breaking up the spell it is clear now what needs to be done to bring the two `produce` calls in sync.

Incidentally, if you'd used shorter variable names<sup>1</sup> in the first place, `ns` for "a stream of numbers", `n` for "a number", `s` for "a stream", you'd have a bit less chance to get confused,

```
(define twice-the-stream
    (lambda (ns)  ;; a numbers stream
        (letrec ([produce (lambda (n s)   ; a number, and a stream
                              (cons (* 2 n)   ; a number, doubled
                                    (lambda ()    ; a stream, repackaged:
                                       (produce (.... s)  ; _its_ 1st element
                                                (force (.... s))))))])  ; and the rest
  (produce (car ns) (force (cdr ns))))))
```

so doing what you're supposed to be doing *(supposedly)* -- i.e. using descriptive names *(but not descriptive enough)* -- is what got you into this trouble in the first place!

---

<sup>1</sup> *supposedly* not a good thing -- but as long as they are clearly described in the comments, I don't see why that should be so.